# How to set criteria on a sub-table in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity `UserCredentials` that is contained by two other entities `MobileUser` and `Owner`.

`UserCredentials` has a `SESSION_ID` that is supposed to return me `UserCredentials.id` such that I am able to set a constraint on `MobileUser` and/or `Owner` like:

```
get owner 
  where 
    owner.userCredentials.id == userCredentials.getIdBySessionId(sessionId)
```

But I'm quite stuck here:

```
private long getOwnerId(Session session) throws NotFoundException {
    
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = getThreadLocalRequest();
    String sessionId = httpRequest.getSession().getId();
    
    if(session.getTransaction().isActive() == false) {
        session.beginTransaction();
    }
    
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(UserCredentials.class);

    // HOW TO DO SOMETHING LIKE DESCRIBED ABOVE?
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<UserCredentials> credentials = cr.list();
    
    if(credentials.isEmpty()) {
        throw new NotFoundException("Session id not found: " + sessionId);
    }
    
    logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "Retrieving owner id of userId: " + credentials.get(0).getUserId());
    
    return credentials.get(0).getId();
}
```

Can anybody show me how this is done in a "*good*" way - meaning that I don't want to fetch multiple times if not necessary. I would like to set the constraints and then call `criteria.list()` to get the desired data.

## Entities:

---

**Owner.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "owner")
public class Owner implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5932700164951552452L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private UserCredentials userCredentials;

    // ...
}
```

**UserCredentials.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_credentials", 
    uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "USER_ID" }) 
    , @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "SESSION_ID" })})
public class UserCredentials extends AbstractTimestampEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1749547554922053458L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="SESSION_ID")
    private String sessionId;
}
```